# Passing a value to an object of the class, how is that possible?

Tags: c++, class, object

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
  
class Complex
{
private:
    double real;
    double imag;
  
public:
   
    Complex(double r = 0.0, double i = 0.0) : real(r), imag(i) {}
  
    bool operator == (Complex rhs) {
       return (real == rhs.real && imag == rhs.imag)? true : false;
    }
};
  
int main()
{
    Complex com1(3.0, 0.0);
  
    if (com1 == 3.0)
       cout << "Same";
    else
       cout << "Not Same";
     return 0;
}
```

here,

```
if (com1 == 3.0)
```

we are passing 3.0 to an object rhs of Complex class, but how is that possible? An object can't have a single value, can it?

also, if rhs = 3.0 is not possible then maybe constructor of Complex class is being called but here constructor takes two arguments and we are passing a single argument??

this example is taken from- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-93/

Comment: `operator ==` should be `const`. `return cond ? true : false;` might simply be `return cond;`.

Comment: What did you think the `i = 0.0` bit did? Do you recognize default arguments when they're using in functions other than constructors?

Comment: @Useless oh i get it now, yes and now i recognize that the img = 0.0 so sorry didn't look at that, but if img = 0.0 wasn't there this would give me an error right? as there are no values initialized for img.

Comment: If the constructor parameters (well, the second one) weren't defaulted, this constructor wouldn't be eligible for converting the double `3.0` to a temporary `Complex{d, 0.0}`, that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non-`explicit` constructor that can be called with one argument is a [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor).

```
Complex(double r = 0.0, double i = 0.0);
```

Since this constructor has [default arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments), we can call it with zero, **one**, or two arguments. Thus, it can act as a **converting constructor**.

So, in the `com1 == 3.0`, which actually is the `com1.operator==(3.0)`, the `3.0` is converted to the `Complex` type, in other words, we create an instance of `Complex` using the argument `3.0`:

```
Complex(3.0); // real = 3.0, imag = 0.0 (default value)
```

When we compare, both real and imaginary parts of the two objects are equal (`3.0 == 3.0`), and the `imag` part of the newly created object is initialized to `0.0` due to the default argument in the constructor.

You can avoid such a scenario by making the constructor `explicit`:

```
explicit Complex(double r = 0.0, double i = 0.0);
```

*As a sidenote, generally, an equality operator should be made a non-member (friend) function, which takes two references to `const` objects of the type. Also, there's no need to return a boolean literal when you can return a direct result of comparison.*

Comment: so when i passed 3.0 to rhs object it got passed to constructor which has two arguments, so only one argument was used to initialize real = r = 3.0 and img = i = 0.0 was initialized to zero??

Comment: is it like when function has two args and i pass only one arg, the first one is initialized with the value and the rest to zero? is that a rule?

Comment: @shockproof since this particular constructor is not `explicit` and can be called with one explicitly passed argument, it is used in such implicit conversions. The passed `3.0` (the one from the comparison) is used to initialized the first paramter (the `real` part), overriding the default argument. The `imag` part is initialized from the remained default argument.

Comment: @shockproof no, your constructor has default arguments (both `0.0`) that's why the `imag` is initialized with `0.0`.

Comment: so if i use explicit keyword for the constructor, this this will surely give me an error cause rhs = 3.0 is not possible right?

Comment: @shockproof if you will make this constructor `explicit`, yes, it won't be used for implicit conversions .

Answer (score 0):

Your `Complex` constructor is not `explicit`, so constructor for `Complex` will be called. In addition, you have `i == 0.0` as default, your constructor will be called like `Complex(3.0)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 oops yea... <.< I messed up with cast operator that can have explicit too.